Does this inequality always hold?
Let $f$ be the pdf of a random variable X whose support is in $[0,\alpha)$, $(\alpha>0)$.
Can anyone show whether the following inequality always holds?
$$\int_{0}^{\mathbb{E}[X]}(\alpha-x)^2 f(x)dx \geq  \int_{\mathbb{E}[X]}^{\alpha}(\alpha-\mathbb{E}[X])^2 f(x)dx $$
I have checked that this is true for a variety of distributions and different parameterizations with support $[0,\alpha)$, and I have not found any counterexamples.

I encourage you to choose a more descriptive title, so people who see this question in a list of search results have some idea what to expect.  What is the context in which you encountered this question, or the motivation/source of interest in it?

If $F(x)=\int_0^xf\mathrm{d}x$ denotes the cumulative density, then if $f$ is symmetric, i.o.w. $F(\mathbb{E}X)=\frac{1}{2}=1-F(\mathbb{E}X)$, we obtain that $\int_0^{\mathbb{E}X}(\alpha-x)^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x\geq\int_0^{\mathbb{E}X}(\alpha-\mathbb{E}X)^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x=(\alpha-\mathbb{E}X)^2F(\mathbb{E}X)$. Hence, by symmetry, we get $F(\mathbb{E}X)=\frac{1}{2}$ and so $(\alpha-\mathbb{E}X)^2F(\mathbb{E}X)=\int_{\mathbb{E}X}^\alpha (\alpha-\mathbb{E}X)^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x$. That is of course assuming that $f(0)=0$.

Wrong, but true if you replace $\mathbb E[X]$ in the bounds of the integrals by the median.
Here is a counterexample for your inequality as written. But first, let us rewrite your inequality to highlight the dependence in $\alpha$. Your inequality holds if and only if
$$ \alpha^2\left(\mathbb P(X\leq \mathbb E[X]) - \mathbb P(X\geq \mathbb E[X])\right) + 2 \alpha\left(\mathbb E[X] \mathbb P(X\geq \mathbb E[X]) - \int_0^{\mathbb E[X]} x f(x) \mathrm d x \right) + \int_0^{\mathbb E[X]} x^2 f(x) \mathrm d x - \mathbb E[X]^2 \mathbb P(X\geq \mathbb E[X]) \geq 0 . $$
You can see that by expanding both squares in the integrals.
Any compactly supported random variable $X$ with $\mathbb P(X \leq \mathbb E[X]) < \mathbb P(X \geq \mathbb E[X])$ gives you a counterexample by taking $\alpha$ large enough. One such example is
$ f(x) = 1 $ if $0 \leq x \leq 1/3$ or $10 \leq x \leq 10+2/3$, and zero otherwise.
Now, onto the proof of the following modified inequality:
Proposition: for every integrable random variable $X$ in $(-\infty,\alpha]$ with median $M$, expectation $E$, and distribution $P_X$, assuming $\mathbb P(X=M)=0$,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^M (\alpha-x)^2 \mathbb d P_X(x) \geq \int_M^\alpha (\alpha-E)^2 \mathbb d P_X(x) = (\alpha-E)^2 \mathbb P(X\geq M) = \frac 12 (\alpha-E)^2 . $$
The proof relies on Jensen’s inequality. Note that the random variable needs not be bounded from below, and it does not need to have a second moment.
Proof: I will show it in the case where $\mathrm d P_X(x) = f(x) \mathrm d x$ since this is how you phrased your original statement, but it can be generalized. By expanding the squares, we see that the inequality holds if and only if
$$ 2 \alpha\left(\mathbb E[X] \mathbb P(X\geq M) - \int_{-\infty}^{M} x f(x) \mathrm d x \right) + \int_{-\infty}^{M} x^2 f(x) \mathrm d x - \mathbb E[X]^2 \mathbb P(X\geq M) \geq 0 . $$
Recall $\mathbb P(X \geq M) = 1/2 = \mathbb P(X\leq M) $, so this is equivalent to
$$ \int_{-\infty}^M [ x^2 - 2\alpha x ] f(x) \mathrm d x - \frac 12 ((\mathbb E[X])^2 + 2\alpha \mathbb E[X] )\geq 0 , $$
or, writing $g(t) = t^2 - 2\alpha t$, equivalent to
$$ \int_{-\infty}^M g(x) (2f(x)) \mathrm d x - g(\mathbb E[X]) \geq 0 . $$
This can be $+\infty$ if $\mathbb E[X^2] = +\infty$, but in this case it is positive and the proposition holds.
Note that the function $h(x) = 2f(x)$ if $0\leq x \leq M$ and $0$ otherwise is the density of a random variable $Y$. Then by Jensen’s inequality, since $g$ is convex
$$ \int_{-\infty}^M g(x) (2f(x)) \mathrm d x \geq g(\mathbb E[Y]) . $$
But
$\mathbb E[X] = \frac 12 (\mathbb E[Y] + 2\int_M^\alpha x f(x) \mathrm d x)$, thus since $Y \leq M$ a.s. we have $\mathbb E[Y] \leq \mathbb E[X] \leq \alpha$. Since $g$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,\alpha]$ we deduce that $g(\mathbb E[Y])\geq g(\mathbb E[X])$, thus proving that the modified inequality holds. $\square$

Thank you for the great answer! To check my understanding, you observe the LHS of the expanded inequality is quadratic in $\alpha$ so as long as the leading term is negative we can take $\alpha$ large enough to ensure the entire LHS is negative?

@msantama That is correct.

Thank you for your detailed reply @Thomas Lehéricy.
